Karate delay after first part of scenario outline is complete, then continue for second part
I use Scenario Outline to trigger the same API for five different scenarios where I generate a random ID for each call.
I then need to make another call using the same random ID for each scenario but this needs to happen after 20 minutes.
I don't want to wait 20 minutes for each call. (That's 100 minutes!) I just need to make the first call for each. After all five is done, wait 20 minutes, then make the second call for each. What is the best way to implement this?

Suggestions:

Discuss this as a team and take a decision to NOT automate this test. (recommended)

Convince dev team to add backend functionality to help testing (that will be disabled in production) maybe an extra API to fast-forward the clock or expire the token.

Work with your ops team to run a CI/CD job (e.g. Jenkins) to do this second run. You can save the first run to a file.

Actually do a Thread.sleep() in your test for 20 mins (not recommended).


